# Interpolate unescaped string in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, postgresql, psycopg2

A psycopg2 cursor takes a string with escaped substrings that represent text/char/varchar values. For instance, to utilize a stored procedures that inserts into a table:

```
cur.execute('SELECT insert_profile("name", "favorite color example")')
```

My problem occurs when I try to use string interpolation to insert variable the string that is passed to the execute function.

I've tried to just use double quotes on the variables and single quotes on the string literal, but this just performs the usual operation. Eg:

```
name = "Harry"
color = "Blue"
cur.execute('SELECT insert_profile({0}, {1})'.format(name, color)
```

I've also tried to nest the variables, but it inserts the literal nested string into the database:

```
name = "'Harry'"
color = "'Blue'"
```

What is the correct approach? Sorry if the answer is elsewhere on SO or the internet. I haven't had success looking around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the psycopg web page:

```
cur.execute(
...     """INSERT INTO some_table (an_int, a_date, another_date, a_string)
...         VALUES (%(int)s, %(date)s, %(date)s, %(str)s);""",
...     {'int': 10, 'str': "O'Reilly", 'date': datetime.date(2005, 11, 18)})
```

The query string has placeholders that refer to keys in the dictionary, and the driver will interpolate the values with appropriate quoting, escaping etc. which can save you quite a lot of trouble.

More importantly: you should never build queries through string operations like concat operation or `format`. This leaves a huge security hole due to SQL injection. Let the driver do the hard work!